# Sending an Enter/New line character to Cisco ASA from Unix using Korn Shell Script

Tags: firewall, enter, cisco, asa

I am writing a script to login to a Cisco ASA device and input a few ACLs into the configuration.

I have created a Korn Shell Script and executing the .sh file from a Ubuntu box. I am able to login to the Cisco ASA box successfully. The problem is that once i login, the device should get into the Privileged Exec mode. I can achieve this by sending the Cisco keyword "enable". This i am successfully able to do. Now after this I want to pass a new line character so that i could feed the password from the script.

The issue i face here is once i give enable, the control goes to the Cisco ASA terminal and it is not in the script. Please suggest